# How do I resolve a "section type conflict" compile error and best practices for using section attribute with gcc

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, embedded

I am using Android NDKr8 and by extension gcc to compile some library code that is shared across multiple platforms including some embedded ones.  This code uses segments to put a bunch of elements into a contiguous memory space.  The compile is generating a  "error:  variable_name causes a section type conflict".

We use a macro to declare the segment attribute:

```
# define DB_SEGMENT __attribute__ ((__section__ ("DBSegment")))
```

The above variable_name is declared as follows:

```
dbStruct const variable_name[] DB_SEGMENT = {
    {conststringvalue0, sizeof(conststringvalue0)},
    …more like this
};
```

dbStruct is

```
typedef struct dbStruct
{
    const char * const  address;
    const UINT16        stringSize;
} dbStruct;
```

conststringvalue0 is declared like so:

```
const char conststringvalue0[] DB_SEGMENT = "some string value";
```

This same code compiles in Xcode using its default compiler with only a small modification in the declaration of the DB_SEGMENT macro.  This is deeper C than I am used to so any help would be appreciated.  Google has some references to the error but the fix for it is not clear. Is there a better strategy for setting up a specific contiguous memory section?

In response to a comment, here is the only difference fromthe correctly compiling version on XCode:

```
#define DB_SEGMENT __attribute__ ((section ("DBSegment,DBSection")))
```

Comment: What is the benefit of going to all this effort?  Why not simply let the compiler organize the memory layout?

Comment: I am attempting to use an existing code base that was originally targeted for embedded devices and used this method to create an in memory database.  It is a requirement of the project to include the functionality that uses this in memory database and it is not an option to re-implement the logic that makes use of it.

Comment: What do you have to change in the XCode version? And what kind of embedded devices were targeted by this code base, ARM processors?

Comment: The port was done originally for XCode and the the only difference at this point is the #define for DB_SEGMENT uses a diffeent syntax for gcc. The XCode version looks like this:  #define DB_SEGMENT __attribute__ ((section ("DBSegment,DBSection"))).  This syntax does not compile with gcc.  I honestly do not know what the processor type is for the embedded devices.  I'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. And my situation is I put the code and variables in the same section. After I put the variable in a different section, the problem dismissed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that mean that you cannot put multiple variables in the same section even if the section has enough space for more than one variable?

Answer (score 0):

"# define DB_SEGMENT **attribute** ((**section** ("DBSegment")))"

I am seeing a space between # and define which is not correct.

Remove that space and try compiling.